# Getting value to append to url with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on updating some code that someone else initially wrote.  I found out they are passing a value to the url onClick, which redirects to the url and allows me to get the value with $_GET.  They use a function to handle this process.  I have a need to change the redirect url, but keep the rest of the process the same.  I copied their function, changed the name, and changed the redirect url.  For some reason, it's not passing the value and I can't access it through GET

Here is their code, which still works on my system:

```
function lab_popup2(id)
    {  
       // alert(id);
        jQuery('#lab_popup').fadeIn();
        var param = RU+'includes/earningdetail2.php?id='+id;
        jQuery('#lab_popup_ifram').attr({'src':param});
        var v = jQuery('#lab_popup_ifram').html();
        jQuery('#consult_popup_ifram').html(v);
        jQuery('#lab_popup_ifram').fadeIn();

    }
```

I pass this function the value like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="lab_popup2('test');">
```

The new code that I'm trying to create is below.  You'll see the only difference is where it redirects, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't pass the value this time.  I did a var dump on GET to make sure, and there was nothing.

```
function lab_popup_emails_completed(id)
    {  
        //alert(id);
        jQuery('#lab_popup').fadeIn();
        var param = RU+'includes/earningdetail4.php?id='+id;
        jQuery('#lab_popup_ifram').attr({'src':param});
        var v = jQuery('#lab_popup_ifram').html();
        jQuery('#consult_popup_ifram').html(v);
        jQuery('#lab_popup_ifram').fadeIn();

    }
```

Once again, I use this code to send a value to the function:

```
<a href="#" onClick="lab_popup_emails_completed('completedpaid');">
```

Since the way I call the function is identical, and the functions themselves are the same except the redirect, I just don't see why the first example works and the second doesn't.

Comment: what's the actual output of your `earningdetail4.php?id=completedpaid` when you call it from a browser? Does it behave as expected. If not, then your problem is in _earningdetail4.php_ and not in the above code.

Comment: This was a great idea for another confirmation of the issue.  It did work properly when I entered the url directly.  So it is somehow in this code, but I just don't see what it could be.

Comment: "I did a var dump on GET to make sure, and there was nothing." is very telling that this isn't a JS issue.

Comment: It would be surprising if it was a JS thing since it's the same code as one that works.  Though since it works when I plug the url directly into the browser as Loopo suggested, I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: uncomment the alert line in the code above and see what value id has when the function fires

Comment: Nothing changes with the alert on.  It still does the popup, but doesn't display the value and no extra alert appears.  So it's almost like it's not fully running, except we know it is or the popup part wouldn't happen.

Comment: I ended up just using php on the earningdetail2.php page to handle the other cases that I was originally using earningdetails4 for.  Makes for more code on the one page, but it works for now.  Once I learn more about classes I might be able to clean it up.  Thanks.